# Изменение label input file на имя загружаемого файла

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

пытаюсь найти input file и записать в него имя самого загружаемого файла, но не могу понять в чем причина ошибки

html

```
<form class="job-form vacancies-form" id="data" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" novalidate="novalidate">
   <div class="title">
      <p>Запишитесь на собеседование</p>
   </div>
   <div class="success-msg">
      <p class="name"></p>
      <p class="text">Ваша заявка успешно отправлена!</p>
      <p class="text">Вскоре мы свяжемся с Вами</p>
   </div>
   <div class="form-content">
      <div class="input-wrap"><span class="input-title">Имя</span>
         <input class="form-input" type="text" placeholder="" name="name">
      </div>
      <div class="input-wrap"><span class="input-title">Номер телефона</span>
         <input class="form-input phone" type="text" placeholder="" name="phone">
      </div>
      <label class="file-label">
      <input class="file-upload" type="file" placeholder="Прикрепить резюме" name="file[]" value="1" size="40" multiple="">Прикрепить резюме
      </label>
      <div class="note">
         <p class="text">Отправляя это сообщение, вы соглашаетесь с </p>
         <a class="link" href="https://klinikajemchujnaya.ru/politika-obrabotki-personalnykh-dannykh" target="_blank">политикой конфиденциальности</a>
      </div>
      <button class="btn-md btn btn--accent" type="submit"><span class="btn__text">Отправить</span></button>
   </div>
</form>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementsByClassName('file-upload')[0].onchange = function () {
        if (this.files[0]) // если выбрали файл
            document.getElementsByClassName('file-label')[0].innerHTML = this.files[0].name;
    };
});
```

ajax

```
  $("form#data").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    var formContent = $(this).find('.form-content');
    var formTitle = $(this).children('.title');
    var successMsg = $(this).children('.success-msg');
    var successName = $(this).find('.success-msg .name');

    $(this).addClass('vacancies-form--success');
    formContent.hide();
    formTitle.hide();
    successMsg.show();
    successName.text(formData.get('name'));

    $.ajax({
      url: 'sender.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      success: function success(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function error(data) {
        console.log('error sending');

        formContent.show();
        formTitle.show();
        successName.text();
        successMsg.hide();
        $(this).removeClass('vacancies-form--success');
      },
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз Вы уже используете jQuery для `$(document).ready`, зачем переходить на чистый js?

Ошибка в том, что Вы назначаете `label.innerHTML` и этим уничтожаете все текущее содержимое тега `label`, включая инпут, который там находится.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.file-upload').change(function() {
    if (this.files[0]) // если выбрали файл
      $('.file-label span').text(this.files[0].name);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="job-form vacancies-form" id="data" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div class="title">
    <p>Запишитесь на собеседование</p>
  </div>
  <div class="success-msg">
    <p class="name"></p>
    <p class="text">Ваша заявка успешно отправлена!</p>
    <p class="text">Вскоре мы свяжемся с Вами</p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-content">
    <div class="input-wrap"><span class="input-title">Имя</span>
      <input class="form-input" type="text" placeholder="" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrap"><span class="input-title">Номер телефона</span>
      <input class="form-input phone" type="text" placeholder="" name="phone">
    </div>
    <label class="file-label">
      <input class="file-upload" type="file" placeholder="Прикрепить резюме" name="file[]" value="1" size="40" multiple="">
      <span>Прикрепить резюме<span>
    </label>
    <div class="note">
      <p class="text">Отправляя это сообщение, вы соглашаетесь с </p>
      <a class="link" href="https://klinikajemchujnaya.ru/politika-obrabotki-personalnykh-dannykh" target="_blank">политикой конфиденциальности</a>
    </div>
    <button class="btn-md btn btn--accent" type="submit"><span class="btn__text">Отправить</span></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I couldn't keep and I have upgraded for you the rating

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Спасибо, Максим!